# Set AM/PM to Time Picker Dialog From String?

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a TextView in which a time is being show in the format `10:00 PM` When user Click on that View, same time must be set to the `TimePicker` Dialog. I am able to set the `Hour` and `Minutes` to the Picker, but in `AM/PM` section. I always get `AM`whether user has set `AM` or `PM`. How can it be solved? any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had Face this Type of Similar issue.

it May Be because you might have set your `hour` element as Below Way

```
hour = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Try Change it to

```
hour = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Hope it Will Help you.

Comment: @Usama Sarwar: if the Answer solve your problem then mark it as accepted answer so that other can trust it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Calendar calendar_date=null;
private TimePicker timePicker;

calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
timePicker= (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker picker, int hour, int minute) {
            calendar_date.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), hour, minute);
            Log.i("TIME", getHourIn12Format(hour)+":"+minute+" "+getAMPM(calendar_date));
        }
    });

private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
    int hourIn12Format = 0;
    if(hour24==0)
        hourIn12Format = 12;
    else if(hour24<=12)
        hourIn12Format = hour24;
    else
        hourIn12Format = hour24-12;
    return hourIn12Format;
}

private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
    return (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==(Calendar.AM))? "AM":"PM";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first provide the data into the timepicker by 24 hours format. later set

```
public void setIs24HourView (false);
```

That will do for you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope i will solve your issue

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
String mDay_time = formatter.format(date);
```

For more [Time Pattern Syntax](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
         //String selectedtime ="03:15 PM"

         //convert time 12 hrs to 24 hrs
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
           SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
           Date date = null;
        try {
            date = parseFormat.parse(selectedtime);
              System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String twentyfourhrstime=displayFormat.format(date);



         //split hrs and min
        String[] parts111 = twentyfourhrstime.split(":");
        String part11 = parts111[0]; // 004
        String part22 = parts111[1];

        System.out.println("value11>>>>"+part11);
        System.out.println("value22>>>>"+part22);
        hour = Integer.parseInt(part11);
        min =Integer.parseInt(part22);
```

and set hour and min value to timepicker..